# Stepping through Python Code in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have an game executable that calls a file called 'MyBot.py' and runs it against its own bot.

I can run the executable from the command file on MacOSX  using the below command:

`./the_file "python3 MyBot.py"`

I am trying to debug the code i have written in Mybot. How do i run the executable from PyCharm so it calls MyBot and lets me step into my code and see the values i am generating?

Running the MyBot.py with the Run command doesnt invoke the executable or lets me step through in it.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/debugging.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this information is readily available on the tool's website, and is not useful by Stackoverflow standards. If the tool's website cannot help, this question needs to be made significantly clearer.

Comment: The high level link doesn't address how to run the issue described above. It speaks to how to set break points and run a single file but not to run an executable and view the code of a component file.

Comment: You can debug MyBot by starting it using PyCharm directly, or a different Python script as the executor. However, passing it as an argument to another tool (one that isn't actually Python) doesn't give PyCharm enough information to know that I Python file is actually being executed.